# Change state of content control checkbox based on other checkboxes state

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have a template .dotm in which I have multiple checkbox content controls. They are organised in groups as follows:

```
[chk_1] Attach all the items listed below:

      [chk_1_1] Item A
      [chk_1_2] Item B
      [chk_1_3] Item C

[chk_2] Send the details provided below:

      [chk_2_1] Info A
      [chk_2_2] Info B
      [chk_2_3] Info C
```

What I'm trying to do is a method to autocheck `chk_1` if any of the subitems are checked, as some sort of failproof system, if the user forget to manually check `chk_1`.
So far, I've managed to do this manually, as follows:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim ctl As ContentControl
For Each ctl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
If ctl.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
    If ctl.Tag = "chk_1_1" or ctl.Tag = "chk_1_2" or ctl.Tag = "chk_1_3" Then
        If ctl.Checked = True Then
            ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("chk_1").Item(1).Checked = True
        End If
    End If
End If         
Next
Dim ctl2 As ContentControl
For Each ctl2 In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
If ctl2.Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
    If ctl2.Tag = "chk_2_1" or ctl2.Tag = "chk_2_2" or ctl2.Tag = "chk_2_3" Then
        If ctl2.Checked = True Then
            ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("chk_2").Item(1).Checked = True
        End If
    End If
End If         
Next
End Sub
```

This code is executed when an ActiveX button `btnSubmit` is clicked and autotick the parent checkboxes, if any of the child checkboxes are ticked.

I want to simplify the code because, over the time, there will be multiple groups with 20+ checkboxes each and the code will be harder to write.

Is there a way to use a string or that checks for the state of all the checkboxes that are tagged `chk_x_y` and then to modify the state `chk_x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could be easier to read and maintain.

If the control naming is consistent there should be no need to check whether the control is a checkbox - the name will identify that.

`Select Case` is an alternative to `If` when using multiple "or" criteria - somewhat easier to read... And in this case it can compare the common section of the tag names for a group. "Greater than" will pick up the longer tag names under the upper-level control that has only the common characters.

Note that you need work backwards through the alphabet when using this approach.

Then, the actual actions performed each time are put in a separate procedure, called by each "Case".

So, when writing the code for multiple controls you can pretty much copy/paste the `Case` then alter the two tag strings for each control set.

```
Sub GetCC_Set()
    Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For Each cc In doc.Contentcontrols
        Select Case cc.tag
            Case Is > "ck2"
                Debug.Print 2
                CheckItems "ck2", cc
            Case Is > "ck1"
                Debug.Print 1
                CheckItems "ck1", cc
            Case Else
                Debug.Print cc.tag
        End Select
    Next                
End Sub

Sub CheckItems(tag As String, cc As Word.ContentControl)
    If cc.Checked = True Then
        cc.Parent.SelectContentControlsByTag(tag).Item(1).Checked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It works very well. Actually, it's way more complex that my current level of VBA knowledge, but I'm glad I am learning new tricks. I was checking whether the control is a checkbox because I thought that using some kind of filters to the controlboxes would somehow make the process faster, instead of checking the tag through all content controls. I am still a newbie.

Comment: @MarianV. Actually, the additional check will make it execute more slowly. An `If` doesn't filter in the sense you have in mind - the `For` still loops all the controls. In the code in the question, it's looping for every tag variation; in the suggested answer, the loop executes only once. A possible "filter" would be to check `If Instr(cc.tag, "ck") <> 0 Then` to jump over the `Select Case` if not a checkbox. Whether this would be faster would depend on whether the document has lots of other kinds of controls and it would be necessary to test how much it would actually bring.

Comment: To my better understanding of the `Select Case`, if layout of the content controls would consist in three tiers of checkboxes (chk1 -> chk1_1 -> chk1_1_1), what adaptation does the code need?  I’ve tested and the code executes only the first occurrence of the `Case Is` where the condition is met. A workaround would be to loop twice using `For i = 1 to 2` before `For Each` line.

Comment: I'm currently on a moble device, so can't test, but: Immediately under the first level `Case Is > "chk1"` put another `Select Case` that tests `Case Is > "chk1_n"` where there order of `n` is the *highest value* used to the lowest.

Comment: Yes, it worked, it's like a nested select case. Testing these days, I've found out that using `Case "chk1_" To "chk1_99"` is the best approach for my code, instead of `Case Is > "chk1"` because it gives the minimum space for error. Thank you for your input, it was very helpful.